# intellij IDEA - Edit Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, ide, java-10

I installed IntelliJ IDEA with Java10.
I am having troubles with the build and run. I am being asked to edit the configuration.
I have specified the JDK 10 in the module settings. Is that a bug ?

[image: I have no option to build and run without configuring]

[image: from here I can open a new window to configure the run settings - I do not know how to proceed though]

[image]

[image]

And, I get this error when I try to compile with a random configuration setting.

*Error: Could not find or load main class 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException*:

**this part is really confusing and not really user-friendly and well documented by JetBrain I find**

[image: which configuration do I need to build the project - the JDK (10) is specified already]

Comment: Right click in a file, Run, or click the `+` button as the dialog says?

Comment: which configuration is required. Selecting application did not allow to build

Comment: Can you try creating a gradle + kotlin project, the lack of a run button in the margin points to an issue with your project setup

Answer (score 1):

Right mouse click on the code window and select Run Your_file_name.kt
It will show you the green button to run the script instantly like below screenshot. click on that button. 
[image]